# DSE Gremlin Console: Cannot modify schema

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin

I have installed DSE 5.0 with the DSE Graph engine, and am trying to follow the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/graphUsingTOC.html) to get a graph up and running, but I have run into an issue with defining the graph schema.

When I try to reference `schema`, for example by doing `schema.propertyKey('test').Text().create()`, I get the following error:

```
No such property: schema for class: Script2
```

I have tried digging around the various config files associated with the DSE Graph, but haven't had any luck finding anything helpful. Has anyone else hit this error before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the commands you need to run to get you started:

```
system.graph('test_graph').create()

:remote config alias g test_graph.g

schema.config().option('graph.schema_mode').set('Development') //Not having this was probably giving you the error.

schema.propertyKey('testProperty').Text().create()
```

see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/QuickStartGremlin.html

> "First, set the schema mode to Development. Development is a more
>   lenient mode that allows schema to be added at any time during
>   testing. For production, Production schema mode should be set to
>   prevent interactive schema changes that can lead to anomalous
>   behavior."